# How to build the Electron application for the Window Store?

Tags: javascript, node.js, windows, uwp, electron

Help build the Electron application for Window Stor.

I compiled a simple application for electron. I try according to instructions from the official site.

I run the command: electron-windows-store --input-directory C:\Brain ++ --output-directory C:\output\Brain ++ --flatten true --package-version 1.0.0.0 --package-name Brain ++

When assembling it asks the following questions:

**? Did you download and install the Desktop App Converter?** - I answer yes

**? You need to install a development certificate in order to run your app. Would you like us to create one?** - I answer yes

**? Please enter the path to your Desktop App Converter (DesktopAppConverter.ps1): -how should I specify the path?** I have Desktop App Converter installed as a store application.

**? You need to install a development certificate in order to run your app. Would you like us to create one?** - I answer yes

**? Please enter your publisher identity:** - What can I specify here?

**? Please enter the location of your Windows Kit's bin folder:** - what here to specify?

Give a detailed instruction or how to respond correctly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Please enter your publisher identity: - What can I specify here?

You need to enter a publisher name. For example: "CN=developmentca"

> Please enter the location of your Windows Kit's bin folder: - what here to specify?

It's the Path of the Windows Kit bin folder. It dependents on where you install it. For example like this: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\x64"

> The first time you run this tool, it needs to know some settings. It will ask you only once and store your answers in your profile folder in a .electron-windows-store file. You can also provide these values as a parameter when running the CLI.

```
{
  "publisher": "CN=developmentca",
  "windowsKit": "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Windows Kits\\10\\bin\\x64",
  "devCert": "C:\\Tools\\DesktopConverter\\Certs\\devcert.pfx",
  "desktopConverter": "C:\\Tools\\DesktopConverter",
  "expandedBaseImage": 
  "C:\\ProgramData\\Microsoft\\Windows\\Images\\BaseImage-14316\\"
}
```

Please read [Electron Apps in the Windows Store](https://github.com/felixrieseberg/electron-windows-store) on github for more details.

Comment: Where can I get expandedBaseImage?

Comment: @VINET You could download the appropriate [Desktop app Converter base image](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=55325) by your OS build version.

Comment: After install your "Windows Desktop App Converter Base Image" you can found it this way: Open Powershell > Get-AppxPackage

Comment: Sorry to up the post after so long, but how do you get that devcert.pfx ?