# Electron Windows Store events.js throws Unhandled 'error' event

Tags: node.js, npm, electron

I'm trying to publish my app to the Windows 10 store, but getting errors, I can't seem to find the solutions to.

```
> node build-store.js

Configuration:
Desktop Converter Location:    false
Expanded Base Image:           false
Publisher:                     CN=******************
Dev Certificate:               C:\data\certs\devcert.pfx
Windows Kit Location:          C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\x64

Starting Conversion...
Cleaning pre-appx output folder...
Copying data...
Creating manifest..
Creating priconfig...
events.js:186
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: spawn C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\x64\makepri.exe ENOENT
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:264:19)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:456:16)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:80:21)
Emitted 'error' event on ChildProcess instance at:
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:270:12)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:456:16)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:80:21) {
  errno: 'ENOENT',
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'spawn C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Windows Kits\\10\\bin\\x64\\makepri.exe',
  path: 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Windows Kits\\10\\bin\\x64\\makepri.exe',
  spawnargs: [
    'createconfig',
    '/cf',
    'pre-appx\\priconfig.xml',
    '/dq',
    'en-US',
    '/a'
  ]
}
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! my-armory-app@1.3.0 appx: `node build-store.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the my-armory-app@1.3.0 appx script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

The build-store files looks like this:

```
const convertToWindowsStore = require('electron-windows-store');

convertToWindowsStore({
  containerVirtualization: false,
  inputDirectory: 'C:\\data\\PRIVATE\\my-armory-app',
  outputDirectory: 'C:\\data\\PRIVATE\\my-armory-app-APPX',
  packageVersion: '1.3.0',
  packageName: 'My Armory App',
  packageDisplayName: 'My Armory App',
  deploy: false,
  publisher: 'CN=***************',
  windowsKit: 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Windows Kits\\10\\bin\\x64',
  devCert: 'C:\\data\\certs\\devcert.pfx',
  certPass: '**********',
  makeappxParams: ['/l'],
  signtoolParams: ['/p'],
  makePri: true,
  createConfigParams: ['/a'],
  createPriParams: ['/b'],
  finalSay: function () {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => resolve())
  }
});
```

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56390843/electron-window-store-build-crashing) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46348557/how-to-build-the-electron-application-for-the-window-store) similar question already, but they don't help at all.
Also tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57935210/events-js183-throw-unhandled-error-event) suggestion, but didn't help.

Comment: as I can see the error us ENOENT ( Which means the file does not exist at a specific place). Make sure ```C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Windows Kits\\10\``` is present in your folder

Comment: Just rechecked all the folders and they are all there but the file `C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Windows Kits\\10\\bin\\x64\\makepri.exe` is not in it. Will check whats going on with that.

Comment: Ok, now I got a different chain of errors, but that helper with the specific error. Turns out Windows directory is deeper then the builder suggests, its `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.17763.0\x64`, meaning. With a subfolder for version. @Sravan If you can make your comment as an answer, Ill accept it.

Comment: Added an answer please check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see the error,

> Error: spawn C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows
>   Kits\10\bin\x64\makepri.exe ENOENT

It suggests that file does not exist at a specific place).

Make sure `C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Windows Kits\\10\` is present in your folder

Also, check all the permissions associated to that folder.

Answer (score 1):

This is what helped me.
When prompted to input your Windows SDK bin folder, don't put

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin
```

You need to specify the folder for a particular version and architecture. Using

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.22621.0\x64
```

worked for me.